# One comma or two commas for a specialization?

Tags: grammar, punctuation, commas

Must I add one more comma (before "will") in this sentence?

> Funds send to this address on any other chain, including main Ethereum chain will be irreversibly lost!

Comment: "Must" is a strong word. The sentence would certainly be better with a comma there. Also "*sen**t***", not "send".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using present tense while you should be using past tense. Use "sen***t***" not "sen***d***".

Using a comma would fit better since "including main Ethereum" is continuing "on any other chain". It mentions that "including main Ethereum" is included in the "any other chain" list.

So the best way to express this sentence is with:

> Funds sent to this address on any other chain, including main Ethereum chain, will be irreversibly lost!

Comment: "Send" was an accidental typo.

Answer (score 1):

A insertion like "including main Ethereum chain" in your sentence can't be separated by a comma from the main part of the sentence on one side only. Think of it as stepping down a level and then back to the main track. Every time you change levels, you need a comma. "Funds sent to this address" and "will be lost" are clearly on the same level.

So yes, one more comma is necessary. The way you wrote it above is like putting in the opening parenthesis and then omitting the closing one.